# django-evolution doesn't work with django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango, django-evolution

I can't run "./manage.py evolve --hint --execute" for my GeoDjango project. It exits with error:

```
File "/home/viktor/.virtualenvs/senv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_evolution-0.6.7-py2.6.egg/django_evolution/db/__init__.py", line 18, in     __init__
module = __import__('.'.join(module_name),{},{},[''])
ImportError: No module named django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis
```

Here's the mutation hint:

```
from django_evolution.mutations import AddField, DeleteField
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import PointField


MUTATIONS = [
    AddField('Geodata', 'position_real', PointField, initial=<<USER VALUE REQUIRED>>),
    AddField('Geodata', 'position', PointField, initial=<<USER VALUE REQUIRED>>),
    DeleteField('Geodata', 'real_lat'),
    DeleteField('Geodata', 'lat'),
    DeleteField('Geodata', 'lng'),
    DeleteField('Geodata', 'real_lng')
]
#----------------------
Trial evolution successful.
```

However, web app runs fine using *backends.postgis database engine. It seems to be a django-evolution problem only.

Any ideas how can I make evolution to work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this simply by adding `DATABASE_ENGINE = "postgresql"` in my `settings.py`.

Looking at the code which uses this variable in `site-packages/django_evolution-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/tests/utils.py` (your path will probably be slightly different), `utils.py` will, depending on the database, call one of the files in `django_evolution-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/django_evolution/db`.  Looking then at the `postgresql.py` file in the db directory, it appears to be a short script which runs a few basic tests against your database implementation. Since the postgis backend would not likely be significantly different from out-of-the-box postgres, I believe it is safe to use postgresql as your `DATABASE_ENGINE` value.